# Spark Job Stuck and Never Finish Executing

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I am trying to do some analysis on a dataset using spark. I am using sbt scala 2.12.8 on my local machine which is (16 GB).

The issue is that Spark Job never finished executing after using transformation and then an action, if I use transformation only or action only it would be executed within seconds.

Code:

```
package wikipedia

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

import scala.io.Source

import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

case class WikipediaArticle2(title: String, text: String) {
  /**
    * @return Whether the text of this article mentions `lang` or not
    * @param lang Language to look for (e.g. "Scala")
    */
  def mentionsLanguage(lang: String): Boolean = text.split(' ').contains(lang)
}

object WikipediaData2 {
  def lines: List[String] = {
    Option(getClass.getResourceAsStream("/wikipedia/wikipedia.dat")) match {
      case None => sys.error("Please download the dataset as explained in the assignment instructions")
      case Some(resource) => Source.fromInputStream(resource).getLines().toList
    }
  }

  def parse(line: String): WikipediaArticle2 = {
    val subs = "</title><text>"
    val i = line.indexOf(subs)
    val title = line.substring(14, i)
    val text  = line.substring(i + subs.length, line.length-16)
    WikipediaArticle2(title, text)
  }
}

object WikipediaTest {

  val langs = List(
    "JavaScript", "Java", "PHP", "Python", "C#", "C++", "Ruby", "CSS",
    "Objective-C", "Perl", "Scala", "Haskell", "MATLAB", "Clojure", "Groovy")

  val conf: SparkConf = new SparkConf()
    .setMaster("local[*]") // tried local[4] 4 cores
    .setAppName("Wikis Most Popular Languages")
  val sc: SparkContext = new SparkContext(conf)
  
  sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

  // Hint: use a combination of `sc.parallelize`, `WikipediaData.lines` and `WikipediaData.parse`
  //  val wikiRdd: RDD[WikipediaArticle] = sc.parallelize(WikipediaData.lines.map(WikipediaData.parse)).cache()
  val wikiRdd: RDD[WikipediaArticle2] = sc.parallelize(WikipediaData2.lines).map(WikipediaData2.parse)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    // wikiRdd.count() // returned 4086
    // wikiRdd.take(2) // result within less than second
    // wikiRdd.filter(a => a.mentionsLanguage("Java")).take(2) // execution stuck here
    // wikiRdd.filter(a => a.mentionsLanguage("Perl")).collect() // exceution stuck here

    sc.stop()
  }

}
```

on terminal I execute the code like this:

```
$ sbt
$ console
scala> import wikipedia.WikipediaTest._
scala> wikiRdd.count() // returned 4086
scala> wikiRdd.take(2) // result within less than second
scala> wikiRdd.filter(a => a.mentionsLanguage("Java")).take(2)
```

This code snippet also get the Job to freeze:

```
wikiRdd.filter(a => a.mentionsLanguage("Perl")).collect()
```

Spark Job UI

[image]

[image]

I have been stumbled for hours and I have no idea what's wrong.

Any suggestion folks?

Comment: Did you find the issue? Im basically having the same problem where my last logs would be 22/08/21 02:29:04 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 4 is finished. Cancelling potential speculative or zombie tasks for this job
22/08/21 02:29:04 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Killing all running tasks in stage 6: Stage finished
22/08/21 02:29:04 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 4 finished: collect at SimilarNews.scala:124, took 0.158968 s